# CSS not loaded when omitting www. part of URL

Tags: permalinks, css, urls

I have the following website: [www.bibaboegifts.be](https://www.bibaboegifts.be).

- When giving in the URL https://www.bibaboegifts.be, the CSS is loaded.
- However, when giving in the URL https://bibaboegifts.be (**without the www. part**), the CSS is not loaded. Only the content is displayed, but my lay-out is not applied.

Any idea why this is the case & how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen for several reasons - in your case, it looks like you are using a caching plugin that only recognizes `www` links. I suspect if you turned off caching you would not have that problem, but then you'd lose the benefits of caching.

It's best practice (with or without caching) to add redirects so only the www or non-www version of your website can be seen. You can add a line or two in your `.htaccess` file to enforce whichever you prefer - which in your case is probably `www`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These 3 lines say, if someone tries to access your site without "www." in the URL, the server should always redirect them to the "www." version of that URL. This helps search engines know which version of your site you want indexed, and if you use SEO plugins that add canonical URLs, will help reinforce the 1 and only 1 version of each page that should be recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to disable the cache plugin (WP Rocket), but the issue still occurs. Will try to adapt the .htaccess file later on.

Comment: Was resolved by adding the code to the .htaccess file. Thanks Elaine!

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you have already disabled caching plugin and checked. So not sure what is causing this issue. But as per my knowledge, your website must only open with or without www (any one of these).

So I always use below code in my .htaccess to redirect **non-www URLs to www URLs**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So when the user tries to access the website without www, the user will automatically be redirected to URL with www.

Maybe this can help you to resolve your issue.